# In vim yank only text between brackets, not entire line

Tags: regex, vim

Let's say that I have some text like the one below, and I just want to yank the characters between and including brackets to register "a":

```
ss = 'Hello World'
a = ['a','b','c']
# this is a comment
b = ['c','d','e']
```

The best I came up with is (also taking into account this is done within a visual selection):

`:'<,'> g/\[.*\]/y A`

however this will yank the entire lines.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the around syntax. `ya[` yanks around including the brackets, and `yi[` would yank the insides of it.

Refer to `:h text-objects`

Comment: Do you mean `:'<,'> g/\[.*\]/ya[ A` ? That gives me `E488: Trailing characters`

Comment: @duff18 hayden is suggesting the normal mode command. please read the doc he suggested first, the text-objects.

Comment: Maybe my example code was too simple, but I'd like to select only the text between brackets, in a document where not all the lines have brackets (that's why I'm using a global command). I'll edit my post